# LPS Service documentation

Tags: sap-cloud-platform

I would like to implement quota management for service. Document I found says to use `lps-service`. I am not able to find documentation which would help me to understand process.
I am following procedure to register `OSB API` and `SaaS provisioning` (since product will be service and application).
Anybody has link to documentation to read about `lps-service`?

BR

Answer (score 0):

I found some resources.

In short: lps-service is pull type. You poll for events. After deletion of account, subaccount, space. New event will be added to collection of events.

You should create instance of lps-service and bind your application (or get service keys). After binding, you would be able to query for history of changes.